# What should be assumed regarding the upper frequency of sma connectors

Tags: rf, connector, microwave

There are infinitely many sellers of sma connectors of various kind in ebay or other stores. This [one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Chic-1X-Adapter-SMA-male-to-SMA-male-plug-RF-connector-straight-gold-plating-WL/233129511617?hash=item36479a0ac1:g:ZNsAAOSw5IJWcZuW) is an example.
But they very seldom specify what is the maximum frequency at which the device can be used. Is there something generally assumed here? perhaps some rule of thumb (in particular if it is said that the connector is made of brass and gold plated)?

Comment: Depends on the VSWR you can accept.

Comment: Do you have some rules of thumb ?

Answer (score 4):

### Nothing aside from what is in the datasheet.

When you pay for a connector from a reputable manufacturer/vendor, in costs more than from ebay, but these costs comes from quality control, base material, factory tests, etc. You get what you pay for.

Comment: Seconded, very cheap RF connectors are generally a mistake, especially SMA where the geometry actually matters and can cause damage to the mating connector if it is wrong (A too long male pin can for example damage the female mating sleeve). There is a reason connector gauges are a thing in my RF lab.

Comment: What should the exact length of a male pin be ?

Comment: The gory details are in MIL-STD-348B rev 3 which is a free download, but the takeaway is that the pin shoulder **must** not extend past the connector reference plane.

Comment: Buy your components from legit resellers who have datasheets for the parts they sell, like Digikey.com and Mouser.com. Then you can tell what you are getting.